# VB.NET using ReadProcessMemory API

Tags: vb.net, api, winapi, dll, readprocessmemory

I am trying to use basic windows API functions in VB.NET. I have the following code:

```
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class testClass
    Declare Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String,
                                     ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByVal lpProcessAttributes As IntPtr,
                                     ByVal lpThreadAttributes As IntPtr,
                                     <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bInheritHandles As Boolean,
                                     ByVal dwCreationFlags As Integer, ByVal lpEnvironment As IntPtr,
                                     ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As String, ByVal lpStartupInfo As Byte(),
                                     ByVal lpProcessInformation As IntPtr()) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    Declare Function GetThreadContext Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetThreadContext" (ByVal hThread As IntPtr,
                                     ByVal lpContext As UInteger()) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "ReadProcessMemory" (ByVal hProcess As IntPtr,
                                     ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByRef lpBuffer As IntPtr,
                                     ByVal nSize As Integer,
                                     ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean

    Public Sub Test()
        Dim locProcess As String = "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
        Dim iPtr1 As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim startInfo As Byte() = New Byte(67) {}
        Dim procInfo As IntPtr() = New IntPtr(3) {}

        Dim cpResult = CreateProcessA(locProcess, vbNullString, iPtr1, iPtr1, False, 0, iPtr1, Nothing, startInfo, procInfo)

        Dim pContext As UInteger() = New UInteger(178) {}
        pContext(0) = &H10002

        If GetThreadContext(procInfo(1), pContext) Then
            Dim pAddress As New IntPtr(pContext(&H29) + 8L)
            Dim pSize As New IntPtr(4)
            Dim bAddress As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
            Dim iPtr2 As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

            If ReadProcessMemory(procInfo(0), pAddress, bAddress, CInt(pSize), iPtr2) <> 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Success!")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("ReadProcessMemory Error code is :" & Err.LastDllError)
            End If

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("GetThreadContext Error code is :" & Err.LastDllError)
        End If


    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
            Dim tc As New testClass
            tc.Test()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I am getting an error on ReadProcessMemory. The code results in

`"ReadProcessMemory Error code is : 299"`.

I have been struggling to find the issue seeing as the error can be vague when dealing directly with windows DLLs. Any help on the issue would be greatly appreciated. Or, is there another solution to debugging properly (other than LastDllError) that may point me in the right direction of solving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: 299 means `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`: *Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.* You could [start searching](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=readprocessmemory+error_partial_copy) that and see what it means.